# Take Training Business Trip When You Might Be Quitting?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, new-job, job-change, notice-period

I am scheduled to take a business trip at the end of the month for some corporate training being paid for by my current employer.

Since signing up for the trip, I got recruited to go and work for two other businesses. I am in the application process for both. I do not think I will hear about either job before the trip. But likely will shortly after.

How do I handle this situation? Do I still go on the training? It's not a cheap training program, but it was paid for last month. I could get some of the money back for the training, but not the flight.

Comment: I recall this is a dupe but I cannot find it.  Go to training the training.

Comment: *Might* be quitting? it is really 2 situations, you signaled that you are quitting or you are staying.  As of now, you really need to at least pretend to be staying.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I would go even stronger.  Do the training, unless your employer has directed you to not do the training.  They likely will when you give notice, but don't assume.

Comment: What reasons do you have to *not* go to the training?

Answer (score 15):

Until you give your notice and your notice takes effect, you are an employee of the firm. You are being directed to take the training to fulfill your responsibilities as determined by management, so comply.

Having said that, you are making the unwarranted assumption that you are going to get an offer with either of the firms you have applied to. There is no such certainty and you may well walk away empty handed. Even if you got an offer from either of the firms you applied to, you may elect to stay with your current employer if you deem their offer inadequate. Or that their work environment and their office culture is not for you.

The only certainty at this point at that you are with your current employer and that you are being sent for training. Proceed on the basis of the certainties that you have.