# Quitting my job when I have professional training soon

Tags: quitting, training, employees

I have been with my company for a year and I don’t really like my job anymore. I am tired of it.

Problem is that 6 months ago they promised me a really good professional training of three days, and I am supposed to do it in May. I am waiting to attend it since I have waited some time for it, and I am pretty excited.

I think that I deserve this professional training, but leaving my company (300+ employees) just after don’t seem really fair to them.

Do you think that I should leave before? Or should I tell them now that I am not sure I will be staying very long? Like until July - September? Or shouldn’t I tell them anything, just showing my dissatisfaction on various issues with my job?

This professional training is really important for me, and expensive (3000€) so If I say anything, I am scared that they could cancel my registration.

What would you do if you were me? I'd like to leave on good terms.

Comment: Many contracts state that an employee is responsible for paying back the company for training if they leave soon after receiving it. Are you willing to pay that 3000€ if that's the case? I would make absolutely certain before you make your decision.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take Training Business Trip When You Might Be Quitting?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/83434/take-training-business-trip-when-you-might-be-quitting)

Comment: Small relevant detail: Is there are chance the company already paid for the training but can be reimbursed? It is usual that this things are settled by contracts, such that even if you had given notice one month earlier, your training would have been paid for any way.

Answer (score 9):

> What would you do if you were me?

Give the required amount of notice only after you have officially landed your next job.

If that takes you past the professional training, so be it.

Answer (score 2):

One thing for sure: **Never tell the employer you are "planning to quit", only tell them only when "you are quitting".** Only after you have a signed contract from another company, give the notice to your employer and inform that you would like to be relived of your duties on so-and-so date.

As for the training, the delay was caused from their side, there is nothing wrong in participating once it is offered to you. This has nothing to do with your resignation "plan".

Answer (score 0):

First, if you don't already have a written offer from another company that you have signed an accepted then it is not a good idea to quit your current job.

Regarding the professional training, while the training may have benefits for you, the reason that the company is paying for it is so that you can help the company.  Don't be surprised if they cancel based on the fact that you are leaving the company.  The training is primarily to help the company.

Also, you will need to look through your contract you see if you would be responsible for paying the expenses of the professional training should you fail to show up for any reason.  Some companies will require you to pay them back if they cannot get the money refunded from the training.  That is something to consider for the timing of your resignation.